# Network Bug in ethernet cable connection on Ubuntu desktop version with IBM Power architecture

Tags: networking, ethernet

Good evening, I am writing to you from Italy and I use a translator because I do not speak English fluently. I have a machine based on IBM Power 9 on Raptor computing System motherboard, I installed your Ubuntu version 20.04.02 LTS and to use it in desktop mode I installed a graphical environment. During the main Ubuntu installation, everything went fine and he did as all distros do, saw the connected ethernet port, set it up and made it work for him. Doing the test ping and trying to install from the terminal in server mode, no problem, everything normal, everything works fine and interrogating the system, he reports the connected port and all the data detected as an IP address and everything else. As soon as I installed Gnome, or even XFCE or even KDE PLASMA, or canonical graphic environments that we all know, a big problem arises. Ubuntu does not recognize the cable connection and consequently tells me that I am offline. The beauty is that if I try to navigate in the browser, then everything is ok, browse and download files regularly, if I try to download files or install applications via the terminal, everything is fine, if instead I try to download applications or updates from the software center or I try to configure Evolution Mail for example, then it tells me I'm offline and doesn't allow me to do anything. In the icon at the top right, where you see the connection with the three small squares, I see a cross on the one on the right and it says disconnected. I try to connect but I get nothing. Ultimately I think there is a bug when installing the graphical environment, which does not allow Ubuntu to see more, the connection which instead is regularly connected and fully functional. Another problem that I have been experiencing for a long time is on Firefox, the bookmark says that it cannot work because there is a conflict with the security software used by Ubuntu and is therefore disabled. Thunderbird does not open preferences and therefore cannot be configured. All problems encountered from version 19.04 to 20.10 that I tried some time ago. Finally, it should be noted that for 2 times, when I used version 20.10, at a certain point in the Gnome graphic environment, almost all the application icons disappeared, almost all those in the favorites bar and on restart, after it loads regularly the Kernel and log in, Ubuntu no longer starts and always comes back to login. The latter seems to be another big bug in the graphical environment, therefore not related to the Kernel. Is there anything you can do to help me and to fix these bugs that Ubuntu in the Power version has been carrying on its shoulders for years now? Thank you

Comment: Your three unrelated problems should be in three separate questions. Do not summarize your problems -- show us actual input and output in each question. We must see those details to help  you.

Comment: Did you install the server version and later install the desktop environment? What is the result of the terminal commands: `cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml` and also: `sudo service NetworkManager status` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome, now I don't have the computer in front of me, tomorrow I can post the commands you asked me to. What I can tell you is that in any case, when I made a request via the terminal, the status of the connection, the terminal told me that the connection was regularly active in the port where in fact the cable is connected with rj45 and gives me regular IP address that the DNS. The connection is there, the problem is in the graphical environment.

Comment: YES I had to first install the server version because in the Power version, there is only the one available. Then I installed the graphical environment regularly and turned it into a full-fledged desktop. As I told you in the first message, the connection works regularly from the terminal or browser, the problem is the graphical environment.

Comment: We shall see when the results are available, but the networking method is different as between server (netplan) and desktop version (Network Manager). One of them needs a tiny tweak and I believe you'll be all set. Looking forward to the results.

Comment: Good evening, I took a picture, I hope it looks good, in fact I see an error in one line, I don't know if it has to do with my problem.  I remember reading that Ubuntu for some years used netplan instead of network manager, maybe there is a conflict between the two because netplan is not deactivated when installing the graphical environment?  I don't know you tell me ...

Comment: mauriziop9@mauryg5:~$ cat /etc/netplan/*.yaml
# This is the network config written by 'subiquity'
network:
  ethernets:
    enP4p1s0f2:
      dhcp4: true
  version: 2

Comment: NetworkManager.service - Network Manager
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/NetworkManager.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Tue 2021-06-22 19:11:53 CEST; 13min ago
       Docs: man:NetworkManager(8)
   Main PID: 1545 (NetworkManager)
      Tasks: 3 (limit: 26084)
     Memory: 15.8M
     CGroup: /system.slice/NetworkManager.service
             └─1545 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

Comment: giu 22 19:11:54 mauryg5 NetworkManager[1545]: <info>  [1624381914.0980] device (lo): carrier: link connected
giu 22 19:11:54 mauryg5 NetworkManager[1545]: <info>  [1624381914.0984] manager: (lo): new Generic device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/1)
giu 22 19:11:54 mauryg5 NetworkManager[1545]: <info>  [1624381914.1002] manager: (enP4p1s0f0): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2)
giu 22 19:11:54 mauryg5 NetworkManager[1545]: <info>  [1624381914.1017] manager: (enP4p1s0f1): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/3)

Comment: giu 22 19:11:54 mauryg5 NetworkManager[1545]: <info>  [1624381914.1027] device (enP4p1s0f2): carrier: link connected
giu 22 19:11:54 mauryg5 NetworkManager[1545]: <info>  [1624381914.1031] manager: (enP4p1s0f2): new Ethernet device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/4)
giu 22 19:11:54 mauryg5 NetworkManager[1545]: <warn>  [1624381914.1063] Error: failed to open /run/network/ifstate

Comment: giu 22 19:11:54 mauryg5 NetworkManager[1545]: <info>  [1624381914.1144] manager: startup complete
giu 22 19:11:54 mauryg5 NetworkManager[1545]: <info>  [1624381914.1200] modem-manager: ModemManager available
giu 22 19:12:44 mauryg5 NetworkManager[1545]: <info>  [1624381964.0651] agent-manager: agent[b9ac8583bcadc52f,:1.51/org.gnome.Shell.NetworkAgent/1000]: agent registered
mauriziop9@mauryg5:~$

Comment: sorry guys but I don't know how to add a photo to be able to post everything, the second command for the NetworkManager output is long and I didn't have how to post it all, I hope you can understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both netplan and Network Manager are competing for control of networking. I suggest that we amend the netplan file to defer to NM. First, we'll back up the currently working file:

```
sudo mv /etc/netplan/*.yaml  /etc/netplan/ubiquity.bak
```

Now create a new file:

```
sudo nano /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
```

Add the following:

```
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Netplan is very specific about indentation and spacing; proofread carefully twice. Save (Ctrl+o) followed by exit (Ctrl+x).

Reboot. Is there any improvement?

Comment: Hi Chili, ok tomorrow I will try this procedure and let you know if the situation improves.  In the meantime, thank you very much for your help

Comment: Hi Chili555, you are great! I performed all the procedure you wrote to me, restarted Ubuntu, as soon as I entered, as if by magic I immediately saw the 3 squares that indicate the active connection at the top right! The problem is therefore of conflict between netplan and network manager, being that when you install the graphical environment, netplan is not deactivated by the system, it happens that it conflicts with network manager and here are all my problems. Thanks again for everything, now Evolution works too obviously, I have to understand the Firefox problem instead ... Open new ask?

Comment: If my answer has been helpful, Please accept it: https://askubuntu.com/tour Please start a new question about the Firefox issue.